# the strength of the axiom of choice used in forcing

Tags: set-theory, lebesgue-measure, axiom-of-choice, forcing, baire-category

I believe that Shelah's model gives a ZFC theorem of relative consistency results:

$ZFC \vdash Con(ZFC + \text{there is a strongly inaccessible cardinal})\rightarrow Con(ZF+DC+ \text{all sets are measurable} + \text{there exists a set without  the property of Baire}).$

Now I wonder if $$ZF+? \nvdash [\text{there exists a set without  the property of Baire}\rightarrow \text{there exists a non-measurable set}],$$ where ? is a suitable assumption. So ? is not full AC.

I try to show that DC is suitable. By completeness theorem, assume the meta theory of first order logic is ZFC set theory, we just find a model of ZF+DC where all sets are measurable while there exists a set without  the property of Baire.

Now, this meta ZFC can be regarded as a theory in the meta-meta first order logic so completeness holds. But I don't know how ZFC can directly provide such a model, unless we refine this meta theory as ZFC+Con(ZFC+IC) so that Shelah's result applies. Is this modification harmless?

It seems ? can't be DC+Con(ZFC+IC). It may be harder to find a model of ZF+DC+Con(ZFC+IC). If we try the other method by directly weakening the choice in Shelah's result, there seems to be a problem. In the construction of generic extension, at least DC is used, for ctm to choose a generic G and for Levy collapse maybe some "global DC" is used so that it's already enough to construct a non-measurable set. Further, in the argument for generic extensions satisfying certain properties some kind of choice may also be used, but I don't know.

Of course, it's good if there is any direct result in descriptive set theory distinguishing these two regular properties, or Shelah's method could be modified in a forcing-free setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not exactly sure what you’re asking here. If you’re asking about what level of choice is necessary in the metatheory to do relative consistency proofs involving the axiom of choice, the answer is none. $\DeclareMathOperator{Con}{Con}$

Keep in mind that $(ZF + ?? \nvdash $ there is a set without the property of Baire $\to$ there exists a non-measurable set$)$ is exactly equivalent to $\Con(ZF + ?? + $ there is a set without property of Baire $+$ all sets are measurable$)$. So I’m not exactly sure why you decided to rephrase the problem in this way.

You say you want to work in the metatheory of ZFC and unconditionally prove a statement of the form $\Con(ZF + ?? + $ there is a set without property of Baire $+$ all sets are measurable$)$. Assuming ZFC is consistent, this is impossible by Gödel’s second incompleteness theorem, since you would then be able to prove the clearly weaker statement $\Con(ZF)$, which is (ZFC provably) equivalent to $\Con(ZFC)$.

In fact, we know that $\Con(ZFC + $ there exists an inaccessible cardinal$)$ and $\Con(ZF + DC + $ all sets are measurable$)$ are equivalent. See [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02760522). Depending on how exactly one defines “Lebesgue measurable” in the absence of choice, it is possible for $ZF + $ all sets are measurable to be equiconsistent with ZF. If you choose a “bad” definition of measurable, it follows from the claim that $\mathbb{R}$ is the countable union of countable sets, which is relatively consistent with ZF.

Comment: Dear Mark, maybe my writting is misleading, but I don't mean to just work in ZFC unconditionally, but rather with a ground model, say ZFC+Con(ZFC+IC), which is strictly more than ZFC. And I'm asking if this is harmless, as a meta theory, to develop first order logic (add a symbol M in language and an axiom "M is a model of ..."). Also, the measure should be at least $\sigma$ -additive, I think, so I assume at least DC, enough for analysis.

Comment: And I have doubts on the absence of choice to do consistency proofs. How to prove the existence of generic filters? We need choice to show the existence of ultrafilters, at least. Anyway, I just want a suitable, or say best ?? so that ZF+?? +$\exists$ a non-BP set  $\nvdash$ [ $\exists$ a non-LM set], or weakest !! so that ZF+!! + $\exists$ a non-BP set  $\vdash$ [ $\exists$ a non-LM set]. I'm sorry if I'm misleading again.

Comment: @clhs First, the relative consistency statement itself is a statement in first-order arithmetic. The axiom of choice is conservative for all such statements (in fact, for a broader class of statements). So any relative consistency proof for recursive theories that can be carried out in ZFC could also, with some modifications, be done in ZF. We would typically want to use Boolean-valued models (or a variation thereof) as the formalism rather than names and a generic ultrafilter when working in ZF. So ZF and ZFC are equally strong metatheories for this sort of thing, though choice may be useful.

Comment: @clhs It seems harmless enough to me to use ZFC + Con(ZFC + IC) as a metatheory (as long as this metatheory is in fact consistent). Of course we can develop in this metatheory all the usual theorems of logic. I suspect the relative consistency proof could even be done in Peano Arithmetic or weaker if it were truly necessary.

Comment: @clhs We know we can take $?? = DC$ by Shelah’s result. Obviously, we can’t take $?? = AC$. I suspect a workable middle ground axiom would be COSHEP - category of sets has enough projectives. A projective set $I$ is one where all $I$-indexed families $(A_i)_{i \in I}$ of nonempty sets have a choice function $f \in \prod\limits_{i \in I} A_i$. COSHEP states that for all $S$, there is a projective set $I$ and surjection $I \to S$. It is stronger than dependent choice but weaker than AC (which is the statement that all sets are projective).

Comment: I think I understand that, as $Con(A)\rightarrow Con(B)$ is an arithmetical sentence coded by ZF so something like Shoenfield's absoluteness works. But I feel it so weird. Say Boolean valued models. I'm not familiar with that, but it's like we just work on a set of names so nothing seems to be addded, where no choice is needed. And I really don't know how to use this method to do products or iterations, or any place a maximal antichain is needed. Also, we may want some logical compactness in usual forcing arguments, but Shoenfield's absoluteness covers all of these.